# Brownian motion and stopping time with a n degree polynomial barrier

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

It is frequent to see problems in stochastic calculus where we have to play with stopping times based on Brownian motions and a constant barrier $a>0$.

For example ,
$\tau= \inf\left\{t \geq0| W_t>a\right\}$ with $W$ a standard Brownian motion. We know that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ because $limsup_{x \to \infty}{W_t}=\infty . $

We can increase the difficulty by using a linear or parabolic function instead of the constant $a$. For example , $\tau=\inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\mu t+a\}}$ or $\tau=\inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\beta t^2+\mu t+a\}}$ where $\mu, \beta$ are constant, and $a>0$  .

Here again , I managed  to prove the cases where we have $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ , by using  $\lim_{t\to \infty}{\frac{W_t}{t}=0}$

Indeed , if $\beta<0$, we have that $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\beta t^2+\mu t+a}{t}<0$, same conclusion when $\beta=0$ and $\mu<0$.

If $\beta=0$ and $\mu>0$,  ***reductio ad absurdum***, assuming $P(\tau<\infty)=1$, we can build an increasing sequence of stopping time $\{\tau_k\}$, where the kth represents the kth time that the process crosses the polynomials and is strictly above it. They are almost surely finite by assumption.

However,$\frac{W_{\tau_k}}{\tau_{k}}>\mu>0$ and the stopping time sequence tends to $\infty$, we get an absurd result. The case where $\beta>0$ is treated the same way.

Now my curiousity brings me to the following question :

**What happens to $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ when we use a polynomial of degree n ?**

Let $\tau$ denotes the following stopping time $\tau=inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_kt^k}}\}$ with $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{n}$ constant and $n\geq3$. What are the necessarry and sufficient conditions on $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{n}$ in order to have $P(\tau<\infty)=1$?

I have always wondered whether that problem was solved, as I have never encountered it. Is there any general solution for that problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly does $W_t/t \to 0$ help you to show that $P(\tau<\infty)$? For $\mu>0$ (looking at just the linear case) it seems to me that it would tend to favor the opposite.

Comment: "prove the cases" Obviously when $\mu>0$, $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ is not guarenteed.

Comment: @Canardini I could be misunderstanding, but what are those cases? If we don't always have $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ for $\tau=inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\mu t+a\}}$ perhaps those cases will give us insight on $P(\tau<\infty)$ if $\tau=inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_kt^k}}\}$?

Comment: When $\mu>0$, we can assume $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ , we then build a sequence of increasing stopping time $\tau_{k}$, which represents le k-th time that we go above the line.They are a.s finite,and verify $\frac{W_{\tau_k}}{\tau_{k}}>\mu$, which is absurd

Comment: If $a_n<0$, or if $a_n>0$ and $a_0<0$, then $P(\tau<\infty)=1$. If $a_n>0$ and $a_0>0$ (and $n\geqslant1$) then $P(\tau<\infty)<1$ and $P(\tau=\infty)<1$. Is this your question?

Comment: How about the conditions on the other coefficients ? Are they irrelevant ? 
My question is : Let 's define  $\tau=inf\{{t \geq0| W_t>\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_kt^k}}\}$.For which conditions on $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{n}$, do we have $P(\tau<\infty)=1$?

If $n=0$, all constants $a_0$ are fine. If $n=1$, we must have $a_1<0$, if n=2, we must have $a_2<0$, or $a_2=0$ and $a_1<0$. How about the cases where $n\geq3$?

Comment: ?? Please see my comment above.

Comment: I had a glance last time , and I was expecting other conditions on the other coeffcients , but I am going to look at it in details as it seems that we dont have to mind about them as you mentioned (by  extending my reasoning for $n\geq3$. I will come back to you, thank you I appreciate.

Comment: @Did What arguments do you use to confirm these results ?

Comment: Most of them are simple consequences of the fact that the set of times when the Brownian motion is at 0 is almost surely unbounded.